# Find the number and position of elements in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, zepto

How would I, using JavaScript, find this out:

Say I have this HTML:

```
<element1></element1>
<element2></element2>
<element2></element2>
```

I would like to detect if there are 2 "element2" elements after my "element1" element. Also, they are not always next to each other.

How would I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? `document.getElementsByTagName('element2');` Or `document.getElementsByTagName('element1')[0].parentNode.getElementsByTagName('element2');`, or `element.nextSibling`, or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to detect if there are 2 "element2" elements after my element1 element. Also, they are not always next to each other.

Assuming *element1* is a `div` and *element2* is a `span`...

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0],
    spanCount = 0;

while (element = element.nextSibling) {
    if (element.tagName == 'SPAN') {
        spanCount++;
    }

    if (spanCount == 2) {
        alert('There are 2 spans following!');
        break;
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Fzfqb/).

Comment: battle o javascript on stackoverflow tonight ha

Comment: @samccone I think this is my only entry in the *battle* tonight :)

Answer (score 1):

Easy with jQuery:

```
 $('element1').nextAll('element2').size()
```

See http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/